# Computed value and return value for overridden hash function are different

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

I've created a **hash** function for an object. The problem I'm running into is that the value I created in the hash function, isn't what's returned from the function.

```
class someClass():

    def someClass(str1, str2, str3):
         self.str1 = str1
         self.str2 = str2
         self.str3 = str3
    ...
    def __hash__(self):
        hash_val = int(sha256((self.str1+ self.str2
                   + self.str3).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), 16)
        # print's 937929098002453100804....
        print(hash_val)
        return hash_val
 ...

  testClass = someClass('test', 'testClass', 'testCase')
  hashKey = hash(testClass)
  # print's 377513311013302392
  print(hashKey)
```

So when I print from **hash**() I get `93792909800245310080479536979750034401273674738852415427366199722413460820022`,
but when I print hashkey I get `377513311013302392`? Why?

**EDIT**: So I called **hash**() explicitly and I got the number I was expecting, but since I overrode **hash**(), shouldn't I be getting the same value from hash()?

Comment: Why do you call `hash(someClass)`? Don't you mean `hash(testClass)`?

Comment: Yes, just fixed it

Comment: And is this code the exact code that you use and that return the wrong result?

Comment: Yeah, It's pretty similar to the code I have now.

Comment: "Pretty similar" is not enough. Show us the relevant parts of your real code or provide a short, complete example that demonstrates the error.

Comment: The only parts missing were the arguments on how the obj is created, but I didn't feel they were important, since they are unmodified after creation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> Note hash() truncates the value returned from an object’s custom **hash**() method to the size of a Py_ssize_t. This is typically 8 bytes on 64-bit builds and 4 bytes on 32-bit builds.

`93792909800245310080479536979750034401273674738852415427366199722413460820022` is way above those limits.

Try this:

```
class C():

    def __hash__(self):
        return 93792909800245310080479536979750034401273674738852415427366199722413460820022

a = C()
b = C()

print(hash(a))
print(hash(b))
```

Output:

```
377513311013302392
377513311013302392
```